# javascript string character assignment question

Tags: javascript

can someone help me understand this piece of code?

```
let word = 'Nose';
word[0] = 'P';

console.log(word); // logs as "Nose"
console.log(word[0]); // logs as "N"
```

Shouldn't word[0] be 'P' and word should be 'Pose' right?

Comment: Duplicate of [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a “string builder” in JavaScript?](/q/51185/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in javascript. They cannot be mutated but the variable can be reassigned a new value.

```js
let str = "Hello";
str[0] = "M";
console.log(str);
str = "Mello";
console.log(str);
```